# hibernate use other class Id as this class Id

Tags: java, hibernate

```
@Entity
class A {
    @Id
    int id;
}

@Entity
class B {
    @Id 
    @OneToOne
    A a;
}
```

B object never refer to same A object, so I want a.id to be the id of B.

How to write the annotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the B object to the following:

```
@Entity
class B {
    @Id
    int id;

    @OneToOne 
    @MapsId
    A a
}
```

See [the hibernate documentation on OneToOne](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html).

Comment: Must I do the duplication of "int id" in class B? Should I assign it with the proper value(a.id) when manually(not hibernate) new B object?

Comment: Yes, otherwise there is no id field available on the B.class. The id will be automatically filled by Hibernate if you persist the object.